# Can you add a dependency to a Castle component that was auto-registered?

Tags: castle-windsor, auto-registration

I generally use StructureMap, but on a current project I'm using Castle Windsor (2.1). I've found some code to auto-register types and interfaces:

`_container.Register(AllTypes.Pick().FromAssembly(GetType().Assembly).WithService.FirstInterface());`

However I would like to add a string dependency to one of the types. I can do this without the convention like this:

`var registration = Component.For()              .ImplementedBy().DependsOn(new[] { Property.ForKey("someString").Eq("blahblah") });
_container.Register(registration);`

Is there any way I can do this with the auto-registered types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use `ConfigureFor<>` method which lets you finetune your registration on a granular level.